# php errors - Notice: Undefined variable: iAccount_db in D:\iac\htdocs\datas\scripts\iAccount_core.inc.php on line 135

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am running a PHP script, and keep getting errors like:
    Notice:  Undefined variable: iAccount_db in D:\iac\htdocs\datas\scripts\iAccount_core.inc.php on line 135

But I have already defined the variable!

code:

iAccount_core.inc.php

```
...
require_once("iAccount_config.inc.php");
...
function iAccount_level_update($user){
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT exp FROM $iAccount_table WHERE username='$user'");
    $exp = @mysql_result($result, "exp");
if ($exp > -1 and $exp < 61){$update_lev = 1;}
if ($exp > 60 and $exp < 101){$update_lev = 2;}
if ($exp > 100 and $exp < 6001){$update_lev = 3;}
if ($exp > 600 and $exp < 1001){$update_lev = 4;}
if ($exp > 1000 and $exp < 6001){$update_lev = 5;}
if ($exp > 5999){$update_lev = 6;}
mysql_query("UPDATE $iAccount_table SET level='$update_lev' WHERE username='$user'", $iAccount_db);
}
function iAccount_level_size($user){
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT level FROM $iAccount_table WHERE username='$user'");
    $level = @mysql_result($result, "level");
if ($level = 0 or $level = ""){iAccount_level_update($user);}
if ($level = 1){$size = $iAccount_level_maxsize[1];}
if ($level = 2){$size = $iAccount_level_maxsize[2];}
if ($level = 3){$size = $iAccount_level_maxsize[3];}
if ($level = 4){$size = $iAccount_level_maxsize[4];}
    if ($level = 5){$size = $iAccount_level_maxsize[5];}
    if ($level = 6){$size = $iAccount_level_maxsize[6];}
    $size = $size*1024; // return KB
    return($size);
}
function iAccount_level_addexp($exp, $user){
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT exp FROM $iAccount_table WHERE username='$user'");
    $expp = @mysql_result($result, "exp");
    $update_exp = $expp+$exp;
    mysql_query("UPDATE $iAccount_table SET exp='$update_exp' WHERE username='$user'", $iAccount_db);
}
function iAccount_dirsize($dirName = '.') {
$dir = dir($dirName);
$size = 0;

while($file = $dir->read()) {
echo "$dirName/$file"." -> ".filesize("$dirName/$file")."n";
if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
if (is_dir("$dirName/$file")) {
$size += dirsize($dirName . '/' . $file);
} else {
$size += filesize($dirName . '/' . $file);
}
}
}
$dir->close();
return $size;
}
...
$iAccount_db = mysql_connect($iAccount_sql_server, $iAccount_sql_username, $iAccount_sql_password) or iAccount_die('Unable to connect to database. Please check your iAccount MySQL server, username and password configuration options.');
mysql_select_db($iAccount_sql_database, $iAccount_db) or iAccount_die('Unable to select the database. Please check your iAccount MySQL database configuration option.');
```

iAccount_config.inc.php

```
...
$iAccount_sql_server = "localhost";
$iAccount_sql_username = "root";
$iAccount_sql_password = "test";
$iAccount_sql_database = "test";
$iAccount_table = "iAccount";
...
```

Comment: can u show us the code?

Comment: Do you expect people to download an unknown archive from an unknown source, browse your "so long" code (if that's the actual content) and spot the error for you? Why don't you just post here the relevant content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now that you posted some code, you're defining `$iAccount_db` in the correct place, but you're trying to access it when inside the [scope of a funcion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) , while the variable is defined outside of it.

*Bad solution*: make `$iAccount_db` global  (not recommended)

A variant to this would be to make those variable CONSTANTS, since actually that's what they are.

**Better solution:** pass the variable as an argument to your function:

```
function iAccount_level_update($user, $iAccount_db){ }
```

Also, your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection (use mysql_real_escape_string at the very least, when required), I suggest switching to mysqli or even better PDO and use query parametrization.

Comment: thanks.Problem has been resolved

Comment: @Birkhoff, it may due to a change in your php.ini. before, PHP did not display warnings (but the error was there), now it does.